# Solr regex not working

Tags: regex, solr, modulo

Morning everybody ,, this is my first time to use solr after reading some document about q , and fq i want to make query that return all rows that have last digit equal 3 for example .

I tried to use regex like condition `id:/.*3/` , but this return no data .

Now i want to do this using mod function , Please explain your solution .

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression to do that, `q=id:*3` works right out of the box.

You can apply a function query to your field using the {!frange} parser, which will return any document where the result of the function behind it returns a value within the range defined.

```
q={!frange l=0 u=0}mod(id, 3)
```

.. assuming that id is an integer. This will only give you values where the function evaluates as `0`, as both the upper and lower bounds are 0 (and by default, the lower/upper is included in the range).

Comment: thanks so much i make some thing like this ,, but i'm busy so i'm forget to delete question `q={!frange l=3 u=3}mod(id, 10)`